# Is there a way to represent "today" in iCAL

Tags: icalendar

I want to implement time ranges such as year-to-date, and I can't find anything in the iCalendar spec about a representation of "current day".

The idea would be to represent the range of "beginning of year" until "current day", "beginning of month" until "current day", etc.

Is there any way to accomplish this with iCAL?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, other than programmatically, ie dynamically generate the feed so it always uses todays date, thus updating the feed each day. Strictly speaking then one should also update the sequence number & the date modified each time. If anyone is .  It doesn't sound the sort of thing (creating events in the past that are dynamic) that is suited to .ics feeds.  Mind telling us what the business use is? Maybe there is a another way?

Comment: Thanks @anmari. The use case here is to allow users to schedule analytics emails. Users can select when they want emails sent, which implements iCAL's recurrence rules. But we want to allow them to select a period of time for which to run the analytics, so I was hoping to stay in iCAL syntax for that, e.g. (last quarter, last month, YTD).